# Jekyll blog using Rmarkdown

Tags: jekyll, r-markdown, github-pages

I have a Jekyll blog hosted on Github Pages, and I wanted to create some posts using RMarkdown. So far I got a file `Test.Rmd`

````
---
output: md_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = '../assets/images/')
knitr::render_jekyll()
```

Sin plot

```{r sin_plot}
plot(1:100, sin(1:100))
```
````

that generates `Test.md` in the same directory when I click the knit button in RStudio. I would like to:

- Generate the .md output in another directory `/_posts`, so I don't have to move it.
- Write the Jekyll YAML header in the .Rmd file, so I don't have to edit it afterwards.

That way, I can simply create the .Rmd in a `/source` directory, located in the same root as `/assets` and `/_posts`, click the knitr button and commit/push the changes to Github.

Thank you in advance

PS: I'd rather avoid using `blogdown` or changing from Jekyll to Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Run `servr::jekyll()` in the R console to get the .md file in the /_posts directory and delete the .md file in the same folder as the .Rmd file.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the problem is that the `servr::jekyll()` function tries to build the Jekyll website. If you are hosting it on Github Pages, that step is not necessary since Github does the compilation for you.

Comment: My site is jekyll and hosted on Github Pages, so what I've described is what I've always done. Feel free to poke around the repo: https://github.com/sctyner/sctyner.github.io